# Inference using pre-trained model on Tensorflow serving taking almost 12 secs

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-serving

I am using Google Cloud (4 CPU,15 GB RAM) to host tensorflow serving (branch 0.5.1). The model is a pre-trained Resnet which I imported using Keras and converted to .pb format using SavedModelBuilder. I followed Tensorflow Serving installation and compilation steps as mentioned in the [installation docs](https://tensorflow.github.io/serving/setup#prerequisites).Did a bazel build using :

> bazel build tensorflow_serving/...

Doing inference on an image from my local machine using a python client, gave me results in approximately 23 secs.This I was able to fine tune a bit by following the advice [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/serving/issues/401). Replaced the bazel build to the below command  to use CPU optimization. This brought the response time down to 12 secs.

> bazel build -c opt --copt=-mavx --copt=-mavx2 --copt=-mfma
>   --copt=-msse4.2  //tensorflow_serving/model_servers:tensorflow_model_server

Other stuff I tried which resulted in no difference to response times..
1. Increased 4 CPU to 8 CPU machine 
2. Tried on a GPU Tesla K80 + 4 CPU machine

I haven't tried batch optimization , as I am currently just testing it out with a single inference request. The configuration doesnt user docker or Kubernettes.

Appreciate any pointers which can help in bringing down the inference times. Thanks !

Comment: Hi There, I don't believe this is a software development question, it sounds more like a configuration issue. You may get better results asking again on http://serverfault.com/ or on a specific tensorflow forum if one exists?

Answer (score 0):

Solved and closing this issue. Now am able to get a sub second prediction time. There were multiple problems. 
One was the image upload/download times which was playing a role. 
The second was when I was running using the GPU, tensorflow serving wasnt compiling using GPU Support. The GPU issue got resolved using two approaches outlined in these links - https://github.com/tensorflow/serving/issues/318 and https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/4841